# Minidom (XML Parsing) with Python - dont want geting any childs child nodes

Tags: python, xml, parsing, minidom

I'm using Minidom (Python XML Parser)

Example:

```
> <layer1>
>   <layer2>
>     <element>1</element>
>     <if>
>       <element>2</element>
>     </if>
>     <element>3</element>
>   <layer2> 
> </layer1>
```

I'm using the ".getElementsByTagName" in the < layer2 > and get every < element >< /element > within the one in the < if >< /if > braces, is there a easy way to just grap the one in the < layer2 >: < element >1< /element >< element >3< /element > ?

I searched through the minidom Documentation and found nothing but this:

> Document.getElementsByTagName(tagName)
>       Search for all descendants (direct children, children’s children, etc.) with a particular element type name.

Hope someone can help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `Element` has a `childNodes` property that has all of that element's (direct) children. Iterating over those, then checking every child to see if it is one of the elements you're looking for, should do what you want.

```
for child in layer2_element.childNodes:
    if child.tagName == 'element':
        ...  # do something with `child`
```